# Button in an AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

How would I set up the onClickListener for a button inside an alertDialog?
Do I just use the onClick of the whole activity or do I make a new one inside the alertDialog builder?

EDIT: Sorry I didn't make it clear first time but this isn't for the positive/negative buttons. This is for a button within a custom xml.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting a standard button to dismiss the dialog then @Sergio is correct. If you are using a custom xml layout:

Use the findViewById and attach a specific listener for that button. Using an activity wide click handler would cause you problems if you were to add another button.

Android docs shows this as:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a builder for building the alert dialog, then set the new button similar to this:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    //your code
    dialog.dismiss();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using alert dialog then, create button in alertdialog and set Dialoginterface.onClicklistner.

Or If you are creating custom dialog with your own view then set click listener on button.